# Comparing two CSV files in PHP out of memory

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I am comparing two CSV files in PHP. I am only interested in knowing that the column names are the same and not interested in the data (at least for now).

This is a generic script that handles any CSV file I choose to upload. The file I am uploading is compared against a set sample file (so I can only upload the file if a sample has been provided). This sample file only contains a few lines of data so is not large by any stretch. The file I am uploading can range from 500kb to about 10mb (the one I am uploading is 7,827,180 bytes).

Everything has been fine until today when I started getting this message:
"Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 7835372 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\errcoaching\app\handlers\file_upload_parse.php on line 8" (line 8 refers to line 2 in my sample (the first line inside my function).

```
function check_csv($f_a, $f_b){
    $csv_upload = array_map("str_getcsv", file($f_a,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES))[0]; // This is line 8
    $csv_sample = array_map("str_getcsv", file($f_b,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES))[0];
    $match = 'true';
    foreach ($csv_sample as $key => $value) {
        if($value != $csv_upload[$key]){
            $match = 'false';
            break 1;
        }
    }
    return $match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the whole file into an array, then disgarding all but the 1st line.

Instead you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php to read only the 1st line:

```
$handle_a = fopen($f_a, "r");
$handle_b = fopen($f_b, "r");
$csv_upload = fgetcsv($handle_a);
$csv_sample = fgetcsv($handle_b);
//the rest of your code
fclose($handle_a);
fclose($handle_b);
```

You should probably also handle file read errors

Comment: Thanks for that, i will give it a go but certainly feels right!